# How do I pass data to modal view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having problems passing data to modal view. Either modal view doesn't open at all or reads data from first item every time I open it.
The biggest problem I have is that I don't know jQuery.
I want a button to open a modal that reads a variable of my item in this case item.Code. Items are in a foreach loop.

This is how i want my code to look.

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 50px">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border: 1px dotted #fff; text-align:center; display: inline-block">
        <h4>@item.Name</h4>

        <!-- Button to open modal view here for this specific item -->

    </div>
}
```

I tried it with and without a partial view.
This is the code I currently have which just opens a modal window but doesn't show anything else.
I know the problem is in id's, but I tried to change all id's to unique ones which caused even more problems.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border: 1px dotted #fff; text-align:center; display: inline-block">
        <h4>@item.Name</h4>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Details" id="@item.id" onclick="Details(this.id);" />


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Raw(item.Code);
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<script>
    function Details(id) {
        $.get("@Url.Action("preview","Generator")/"+id, function (data) { $('.modal-body').html(data); });
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal' , function (e) {
        $('.modal-body').html("");
    })
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Eg. This is the your html after the complete the forLoop**

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 50px">
     <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border: 1px dotted #fff; text-align:center; display: inline-block">
          <h4>Item Name - 1</h4>
          <button type="button" data-item="Item Name - 1" class="btn btn-default clsDetails">Details</button>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border: 1px dotted #fff; text-align:center; display: inline-block">
          <h4>Item Name - 2</h4>
          <button type="button" data-item="Item Name - 2" class="btn btn-default clsDetails">Details</button>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border: 1px dotted #fff; text-align:center; display: inline-block">
          <h4>Item Name - 3</h4>
          <button type="button" data-item="Item Name - 3" class="btn btn-default clsDetails">Details</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**HTML Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="dvData"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Scripts**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".clsDetails",OpenModalPopUp);   
});

function OpenModalPopUp(){
   var itemName = $(this).data("item");
   alert(itemName);
   $('#dvData').html(itemName);
   $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!! You have one mistake in your code (or at least I think it is since it didn't work until I changed it). in Scipts line: `$('#dvData').html(itemName);` needs to be changed to `$('.dvData').html(itemName);` .